# Where to write mutable and where immutable logic with @redux/toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I had the exact same problem as in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431457/a-state-mutation-was-detected-inside-a-dispatch-even-with-toolkit). With this code:

```
set(state, action) {
  const { id, value, field } = action.payload
  const range = state.ranges.find(r => r.id === id)
  range[field] = new Date(value) //action.payload.field can be either "start" or "end"
}
```

Answer to question above was to [not put non-serializable values in state](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).

Does it mean I can't have an array of objects that look like this `{ id, start, end }` in my state? If that's the case (which I hope it is not) how do I store it?

If I can't store it otherwise do I need to just write immutable logic for such cases?

Comment: An array of objects is serializable, promises, and functions aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can totally have objects in state, and Redux Toolkit's use of Immer allows you to "mutate" those objects.

My answer in the other issue was pointing out that `Date` objects are not inherently serializable, so you shouldn't be saving them in the Redux state.

Comment: Thanks, I realized way to late that I'm storing Date instances in state